# Creation function for database MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have a database 'excursions' with information about customers, buses, drivers, bills and excursions. I need to create a function that calculates payment for a specified month for one customer. I`ve already created it. Also i`ve created a procedure that call that function for all customers. But MySQL Workbench tell me that there is a mistake. Help me to fix it

```
USE excursions_test;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION  sum_bill(excursion_id INT, for_begin DATE, for_end DATE) RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
       SELECT excStart = excursion.start_date, excEnd = excursion.end_date, excPrice =( excursion.excursion_duration*excursion.number_of_tourists*bus_model.fuel_for_km*excursion.distance)*1.5,
        IF(excStart < for_begin OR excEnd > for_end, 0, 
        IF(excStart <= for_begin OR excEnd >= for_end AND excEnd <= for_end, DATEDIFF(for_begin, excEnd)*excPrice/30,
        IF(excStart >= for_begin AND excEnd >= for_begin AND excEnd <= for_end, DATEDIFF(excStart, excEnd)*excPrice/30,
        IF(excStart >= for_begin AND excEnd >= for_end, DATEDIFF(excStart, for_end)*excPrice/30,
        IF(excStart <= for_begin AND excEnd >= for_end, DATEDIFF(for_begin, for_end)*excPrice/30, 0)))))
        FROM excursion JOIN bus_model ON excursion.bus_model_id = bus_model.bus_model_id
        WHERE excursion.excursion_id = excursion_id;
        RETURN 0;
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE bill_creator(for_begin DATE, for_end DATE)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO bill(excursion_id, start_date, end_date, amount)
    SELECT excursion.excursion_id, for_begin, for_end, dbo.sum_bill(dbo.excursion.excursion_id, for_begin, for_end)
    FROM excursion
    WHERE (excursion.start_date >= for_begin AND excursion.end_date <= for_end)
        OR (excursion.end_date >= for_begin AND excursion.end_date <= for_end)
        OR (excursion.start_date<= for_begin AND excursion.end_date>= for_begin);
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL bill_creator ('2021-10-01', '2021-10-31')
```

The mistake: Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Comment: Are you sure this is mysql the use of dbo would indicate sql_server..

Comment: What's the point of the function? It always return 0 as a result. And it has a select statement in it that just returns a resultset, which is not allowed as per the error message.

Comment: If you are migrating code from ms sql server to mysql, then you need to convert all code to mysql syntax, not just parts of it!

Answer (score -1):

You are returning a single row resultset that has multiple columns but the return type of the function is int.

I haven't tested the following so you might need to tweak it, but the error should be fixed if you replace the section

```
   SELECT excStart = excursion.start_date, excEnd = excursion.end_date, excPrice =( excursion.excursion_duration*excursion.number_of_tourists*bus_model.fuel_for_km*excursion.distance)*1.5,
    IF(excStart < for_begin OR excEnd > for_end, 0, 
    IF(excStart <= for_begin OR excEnd >= for_end AND excEnd <= for_end, DATEDIFF(for_begin, excEnd)*excPrice/30,
    IF(excStart >= for_begin AND excEnd >= for_begin AND excEnd <= for_end, DATEDIFF(excStart, excEnd)*excPrice/30,
    IF(excStart >= for_begin AND excEnd >= for_end, DATEDIFF(excStart, for_end)*excPrice/30,
    IF(excStart <= for_begin AND excEnd >= for_end, DATEDIFF(for_begin, for_end)*excPrice/30, 0)))))
    FROM excursion JOIN bus_model ON excursion.bus_model_id = bus_model.bus_model_id
    WHERE excursion.excursion_id = excursion_id;
    RETURN 0;
```

with

```
SELECT excStart = excursion.start_date, excEnd = excursion.end_date, excPrice =( excursion.excursion_duration*excursion.number_of_tourists*bus_model.fuel_for_km*excursion.distance)*1.5;
    FROM excursion JOIN bus_model ON excursion.bus_model_id = bus_model.bus_model_id
    WHERE excursion.excursion_id = excursion_id;

IF(excStart < for_begin OR excEnd > for_end)
BEGIN
    RETURN 0;
END;

IF(excStart <= for_begin OR excEnd >= for_end AND excEnd <= for_end)
BEGIN
    RETURN  DATEDIFF(for_begin, excEnd)*excPrice/30;
END;

IF(excStart >= for_begin AND excEnd >= for_begin AND excEnd <= for_end)
BEGIN
    RETURN  DATEDIFF(excStart, excEnd)*excPrice/30;
END;

IF(excStart >= for_begin AND excEnd >= for_end)
BEGIN
    RETURN  DATEDIFF(excStart, for_end)*excPrice/30;
END;

IF(excStart <= for_begin AND excEnd >= for_end)
BEGIN
    RETURN  DATEDIFF(for_begin, for_end)*excPrice/30, 0;
END;

RETURN 0;
```

Comment: 1) You have not declared any variables. 2) select variable_name = expression ... is ms sql syntax, not mysql. Mysql would require select into. See P.Salmon's comment under the question askin what database product the OP uses.

Comment: 1) The variables were already declared before the section of code that I suggested this as a replacement for. 2) I saw that comment and worked on the assumption that it is in fact sql server based on the syntax and naming.

Comment: 1) there are not variables declared anywhere, apart from the parameters in the stored proc and the function. 2) if you assumed it was ms sql and not mysql, then you should have made this explicit in your answer and convert all the syntax to ms sql server (delimiter, function declaration, use of @ in variable names, etc). However, the error message and the syntax for declaring the stored procedure and the function, along with the question tagging suggests that mysql was used.